# pr2_interactive_manipulation_desktop.launch is missing on groovy

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I tried to test pr2_marker_control package following wiki tutorial[1], but could not find
pr2_interactive_manipulation_desktop.launch file under pr2_interactive_manipulation package.

The file is missing? or the wiki is incorrect?

[1] [www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org) wiki pr2_marker_control (sorry that I don't have enough karma to post url)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61962/pr2_interactive_manipulation_desktop.launch-is-missing-on-groovy/) by [houjou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4804/houjou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the pr2_interactive_manipulation_desktop.launch file has moved into the pr2_interactive_manipulation_frontend package.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [houjou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4804/houjou/) on 2013-05-06**:
Thank you. I fixed wiki page.